# Renew ISession of nhibernate after db has fallen.

Tags: c#, nhibernate

we are testing cases when the database has fallen and restarted, when using the ISession one more time we get an exception. is there a way to renew the session ? 
or better way, get some event through NHibernate that the db has shutdown ?

Answer (score 3):

`ISession`s must be disposed of when *any* database-related exception occurs, so you shouldn't actually try to renew it.